# Scan Directory and display subdirectory and its contents

Tags: php

I have a directory structure like so

```
- images
-- images1/
--- image.jpg
-- images2/
--- image.jpg
-- images3/
--- image.jpg
-- images4/
--- image.jpg
```

Let's say that there are other files in the directories as well.

I'd like to scan each dir, display it as well as specific content that's in each directory, so I'd like to display an array of folder, and only .jpg and .png images but not .gif, for example.

How can I do this? So far I have..

```
public function getImages(){

    $path = app_path() . '/images/';
    $list = scandir($path);
    while ($list) {
        # stuck here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get files with sub folders inside, then you can just use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, then combine it with `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. (My goodness, what a name that is). Consider this example:

```
$path = 'images';
$current_folder = '';
$images = array();
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($files as $key => $value) {
    if($value->isDir()) {
        $current_folder = $value->getFilename();
        $images[$current_folder] = array();
    } else {
        if($value->getExtension() == 'jpg' || $value->getExtension() == 'png') {
            $images[$current_folder][] = $value->getFilename();
        }
    }
}

ksort($images);
print_r($images);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [images1] => Array
    (
        [0] => image.jpg
    )

    [images2] => Array
    (
        [0] => image.jpg
    )

    [images3] => Array
    (
        [0] => image.jpg
    )

    [images4] => Array
    (
        [0] => image.jpg
    )

)
```

Comment: what is the use of two brackets here ..$images[$current_folder][]...only $images[$current_folder] enough ??

Comment: @CodeLover just making sure, what if there are 3 images inside a folder, you wouldn't want them to be overwriting the value every loop. thats why i assigned and appended it as an array

Comment: will it work if i add .$images[$current_folder] instead of $images[$current_folder][] ??

Comment: @CodeLover it will still work, but as i have said, it will only store one value, what if that folder has many images? what if inside folder `images1` there are `image.jpg, image.png, monalisa.png`. you'll only get one if you do that.

Comment: so if we call like $images[$current_folder][]  it is the way of calling multidimensional array right ??

Comment: @CodeLover if you want to access the inside of that newly created array, you can do it by looping it or directly accessing it like: `$yourimage = $images['images1'][0];`

Comment: Hi, thanks. It's perfect. I have one question though and I hope you'd change the answer to this as well so I can see how it's done. Instead of just blacklisting .gif, how can I just whitelist .png, .jpg? So anything that's not in the whitelist would not be shown.

Comment: im on mobile now, but with regards to that, just reverse the condition, instead of `!= 'gif'`, you can change it to `$value->getExtension() == 'jpg' || $value->getExtension() == 'png'` on the if statement

Comment: @user254799 you can check the edit now,i have the code accordingly. good day:)

Comment: What if it's a list of items instead? Besides copy and pasting over and over again, how would I do this with a whitelisted array?

Comment: Hi, here's what I'm working with, thanks to your code. 

https://gist.github.com/ljdevs/ba0d8dbacab8f14e5f07

Problem is that even though there are multiple problems in the directory, it only shows one file. Any way to display al of the files?

Comment: @user254799 yes, i have looked upon the code on gist, and naturally it will only have one value because over the loop, the value of `'font'` gets overwriiten. what you have to do is assign another array, because   in each loop is another batch, so naturally you'll have to do is: `$fontsList[$current_folder] = array('font' => $value->getFilename(), 'path' => $current_folder . '/' . $value->getFilename())` to append all of them.